# PHP While gerando loop a mais

Tags: php

Meu while esta inventando uma contagem a mais. Porque isso?

```
$rsMsgLer = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE para = '".$row['ID_Cadastro']."' GROUP BY de");
```

.

```
<?php do { ?>

...

<?php } while ($rowMsgLer = $rsMsgLer->fetch_assoc()); ?>
```

Deveria aparecer apenas 3 registros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas esta listando 4, um é algum erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque o `do...while` executa o bloco de código antes de verificar a condição e você só recupera o registro na condição. Ou seja, a primeira vez que é executado, não há um registro a ser exibido. Troque o `do...while` por `while` e veja se funciona.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Porque não coloca como resposta para receber pontuação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está em utilizar a estrutura `do ... while` para iterar sobre os registro. Considerando o código abaixo:

```
do {

    <block>

} while (<condition>);
```

O bloco de código definido em `<block>` será executado antes da condição `<condition>` ser verificada. Como no seu problema, a condição é uma atribuição do registro do banco à variável `$rowMsgLer`, na primeira iteração deste laço, esta variável não existirá, gerando o erro apresentado. Para corrigir, basta trocar para a estrutura `while`:

```
while (<condition>) {

    <block>

}
```

Assim, a condição será verificada antes do bloco de código ser executado e, portanto, já na primeira iteração do laço, a variável estará devidamente `$rowMsgLer` definida.